# In Java, how to replace a symbol occurring in multiple places in the string by another symbol at all instances?

Tags: java, string, replace

I have written a method to replace the first instance of the given symbol by another symbol in a given string.

I would like to modify this method so that it will replace all instances of the old symbol by the given new symbol in that string.

```
public static String myReplace(String origString, String oldValue, String newValue) {
    char[] chars = origString.toCharArray();
    char[] charsNewValue = newValue.toCharArray();

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    int startPos = origString.indexOf(oldValue);
    int endPos = startPos + oldValue.length();
    int lengthOfString = origString.length();
    if (startPos != -1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < startPos; i++)
            sb.append(chars[i]);
        for (int i = 0; i < newValue.length(); i++)
            sb.append(charsNewValue[i]);
        for (int i = endPos; i < lengthOfString; i++) 
            sb.append(chars[i]);
    } 
    else 
        return toReplaceInto;
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using `String.replace`? See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: There's a perfectly good wheel already. No need to invent a new one.

Comment: basically this question can be answered with "RTFM"

Comment: @JonSkeet much like any new developer, they probably want to learn how the actual methods are built.  I'm sure this is just an esoteric exercise?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: I am having Java 1.4 in my device.

Comment: @Sen: Given how old Java 1.4 is, it would have been *very* useful to have stated that in the question.

Comment: @sircapsalot: It would have been worth saying so to start with then. I'm all for curiosity, but it's important to know beforehand what the goal is: being able to perform string replacement, or implementing it.

Comment: Actually it was updated to 1.4 recently, earlier we had 1.2. That was the whole reason why we had to implement this Replace Method. So I am looking to change that so that we can have a ReplaceAll method as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`String.replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29). It does exactly what you've asked for:

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence.

---

Slightly OT, but your method for replacing just the first match is much more complex than required, as well:

```
private static String replaceOne(String str, String find, String replace) {
    int index = str.indexOf(find);
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        return str.substring(0, index) + replace + str.substring(index + find.length());
    }
    return str;
}
```

Tests:

```
System.out.println(replaceOne("find xxx find", "find", "REP")); // "REP xxx find"
System.out.println(replaceOne("xxx xxx find", "find", "REP"));  // "xxx xxx REP"
System.out.println(replaceOne("xxx find xxx", "find", "REP"));  // "xxx REP xxx"
System.out.println(replaceOne("xxx xxx xxx", "find", "REP"));   // "xxx xxx xxx"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replace method as follows:

```
origString = origString.replace(oldValue, newValue);
```